# I couldn't use Echarts Zrender draw Image in vue project,but works in html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, echarts

I want to make a lot of pictures on my canvas, I can redraw/rotate/zoom, so I found the ZRender of ECharts. The example inserts the image on the canvas, the html executes fine, but I put it in vue It can't be rendered, and there are no errors. Thanks for your help!

```py
<template>
    <div id="main"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import zrender from 'zrender'

    export default {
      name: "zrender_image",
      data() {
        return {}
      },
      methods: {
        order: function () {
          var zr = zrender.init(document.getElementById('main'));
          for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
              var image = new zrender.Image({
                position: [i * 500, j * 500],
                scale: [1, 1],
                style: {
                  x: 0,
                  y: 0,
                  image: 'bg.jpg',
                  width: 500,
                  height: 500
                },
                draggable: true
              });
              zr.add(image);
            }
          }
          ;
        },
      },

      mounted() {
        this.order();
      }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
        html, body, #main {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
</style>
```

I expect the image can be draw in main div.

Comment: @all need your help

Answer (score 0):

Why I can't answer my question.I have found he problem is in image src. It should be

```
src = require("bg.jpg")
```